# How can i read a variable value from database in one of the Rails environment files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to setup a custom logger with a secret key in config/environments/(dev/prod).rb

The value of the secret key is stored in the database and i have a model that pulls the value, but i think there is no DB connection yet when Rails loads the env files.

Is there any way to have that value pulled from the database inside an environment file in Rails?

for example my model is `ApplicationConfig`

and i need to write in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.secret_key = ApplicationConfig.value_for('var_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `config.after_initialize`.  When this callback runs, Rails has been fully loaded.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: what i am trying to do is insert the `config.logger` inside of the `config.after_initialize` because the logger need a a DB key from the DB, but while i see no error that block is totally ignored and Rails keeps logging inside of the development.log file